# Reactjs multiple form submit

Tags: reactjs, multiple-forms

In my case, i would like to submit multiple forms in reactjs. But i have no idea on how to get the multiple form at Parent Component and submit.

here is my code:

```
class BulkEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            customCompanies: []
        };

        this.forms = [];

        this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
        this.handleBulkSaveClick = this.handleBulkSaveClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleBulkSaveClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    /*
     * -- Add Children
     */
    onAddChild() {
        this.state.items.push(BulkEditorForm.defaultProps);

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items
        });
    }

    render() {
        var forms = this.state.items.map(function(item, index) {                    
            return (
                    <li className="list-group-item" key={index}>                    
                        <BulkEditorForm companies={this.state.customCompanies} item={item} 
                            ref="editorform"></BulkEditorForm>
                    </li>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {forms}
                    <li className="list-group-item"> 
                        <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right" role="group" aria-label="bulk-buttons">
                            <a href="javascript:;" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onAddChild.bind(this)}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleBulkSaveClick}>Bulk Save</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is next class

```
export default class BulkEditorForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        alert("Submit");
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <form action='#' method="post" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>                
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-link">Save</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop of rendering form list, use different ref value for each form:

```
<BulkEditorForm companies={this.state.customCompanies} item={item} 
                            ref={"editorform"+index}></BulkEditorForm>
```

Then after all forms are rendered, access the form list by refs in your Parent Component, which means adding `componentDidMount()` function as follows:

```
class BulkEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //using basic javascript "FOR" loop ^^
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) { 
      this.forms.push(this.refs["editorform"+index]);
    }
  }

}
```

I didn't have time for testing all the code, but that's the idea! If it doesn't work yet, feel free to post here some error logs, then we may solve it together, thanks ^^